# How do I remove tray icon on application uninstall in C#

Tags: c#, setup-project, uninstallation, trayicon

I have an application with tray icon. I am using notifyicon to do this job.
I have created its setup in Visual Studio which installs and uninstall the application.

Problem is when I uninstall the program, its tray icon is not removed and even after the program has been uninstalled, I can click on the icon and start the app even though its .exe file from back end has been deleted by the uninstaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to create in your tray application a background thread which will wait for a named event to be signaled. Then your uninstaller should set this event into the signaled state. When the event is signaled the tray application just exits.

In your tray application's background thread:

```
EventWaitHandle ev = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "MyCloseEventName");
ev.WaitOne();
```

In your uninstaller:

```
EventWaitHandle ev = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("MyCloseEventName");
ev.Set();
```

Comment: Ok I got the part about creating background thread but how do I call it from uninstaller? Because in uninstaller I don't see any place to write any code so I can raise this event.

Comment: But problem is where do I write this code in uninstaller? There is no option to write code. Check attached screenshot and you will see there is no .cs or other file to write code. http://i.imgur.com/18yxM.jpg

Comment: You need to create a [Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in the deployment project.

Comment: In custom action the only option available is to run an exe, dll, vbs or js file at Install, Commit, Rollback and Uninstall. So what I have done is I have created another .exe which runs at the time of uninstall and it kills that process (my application). But it doesn't remove tray icon which remains there and only goes one someone clicks on it. Is there a way to hide icon of one application from another?

Comment: You do not need to kill the process, it is a rough way to terminate the application. Just set event in this another exe.

Comment: I haven't tried your solution yet because there is no option to write code and it seems I will need to change setup project type. But I will accept it as right answer.